# How to do a change in string of file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a config file xyz.conf which contains some fields and I want to do little change in between it according to the requirement of user. (i.e ERROR,INFO,DEBUG,WARN)
How can I do that using shell script?

Example
I have following lines

```
match => ["log_EventType", "ERROR"]
add_tag => [ "loglevelError" ]
if "loglevelError" in [tags] {
```

I want to changes these lines in

```
match => ["log_EventType", "DEBUG"]
add_tag => [ "loglevelDebug" ]
if "loglevelDebug" in [tags] {
```

What i have tried so far is:
match => ["log_EventType", "INFO"]

For this line I created a script

```
file=xyz.conf
err=$1
sed -i 's/"ERROR.*/"'$err'/' $file
```

and simply I run command ./script.sh  INFO

But in Output I get

```
match => ["log_EventType", "INFO
```

It does not return closing bracket after the word INFO

Comment: I have edit the question you can  read it their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script solves your problem letting users specify any error level and have it replaced throughout the conf file regardless of which error level that was in the file in the first place:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="xyz.conf"
err="${1,,}"
sed -i 's/\(match => \["log_EventType", "\)[^"]*/\1'${err^^}'/g; s/\("loglevel\)[^"]*/\1'${err^}'/g' $file
```

Examples:

```
$ ./script.sh error
$ ./script.sh debug
```

Note: `${1,,}`, `${err^^}` and `${err^}` will take care of upper/lower case but might not work for bash versions before 4.

Comment: I tried this but getting this error ./script.sh: 5: ./script.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: It worked just changed  #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash
Thanks you so much.

Comment: Great solution `#!/bin/bash`. Will add to answer.

Comment: But in log level I don not want whole word in lower case. First word should be capital e.g Info, Debug

Comment: Oh man, that is new information. If you change `${err,,}` to `${err^}` you will get what you want (providing you call script with lower case error levels).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your change. You can also use it with both upper and lower case now.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it is simply:

```
sed -i 's/ERROR/DEBUG/; s/loglevelerror/logleveldebug/' filename
```

It does not return closing bracket after the word INFO in your case,
because you change not `ERROR`, but `ERROR.*`. It means that you want to substistute the whole line after the word `ERROR` and not only this word.

But I think that you want to handle some additional checks/conditions,
that you didn't mention here.
Please do it so we can improve our answers.

Comment: I want is that user can change whatever kind of logs he wants either error,debug,info or warn but just banging my head could not find anyway.

Comment: @MaheenNasir: Ok, then just do like I wrote

Comment: Thanks. @Igor Chubin